# What css code could I use so that the content on my webpage does not change its position the browser window resizes?

Tags: html, css, web, resize

So I'm having trouble with my website. If you would like a link to really see the problem, here it is: http://agarciapackages.neocities.org/ resize the window and you will see that the text beside the window rearranges itself the window size does. If you're looking at the website from a mobile device, it looks horrid because the text goes very far down past the image and I don't want that. I'd rather the user scroll to the right to see the full text than to scroll down really far to see full the text.
here is my CSS code.

```
.homepageImages {
    margin-left:50px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    padding:30px;
    float:left;
}

.caption{
    position:static;
    margin-top:130px;
    font-family:American Typewriter;
    margin-left:670px;
    margin-right:50px;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: It looks fine on mobile

Comment: It looks horrid on large screens, though

Comment: Is there any way to make it look better on a large screen without changing the way it looks on mobile? @junkfoodjunkie

Comment: Well, the first thing to do would be to limit how wide the content can be, for instance using `max-width` in the CSS. Currently, on my full-HD screen, it's a pita to read the text, because each line is way too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a container above the main content, and give some width to that container for desktop devices and also you can target that width for mobile devices using media queries.

```
[checkout here][https://jsfiddle.net/mukeshrana90/vfLbr0rb/3/]
```

Comment: Yes! thank you so much! it worked, I really appreciate it.